# How to make jar file created by netbeans work from any location in the system

Tags: java, swing, jar, executable, netbeans7.0

I have a java desktop application in `netbeans`. I have created an executable jar file for the project using clean and build command provided by the `netbeans`. By using this command the executable jar file gets created under netbeansProjects//dist/.jar. I am able to execute this jar file from command line using java -jar .jar from within project path. But the problem is that when i move this jar outside of netbeans projects folder, say to desktop and run the jar file, it is giving error of type "Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`". How to solve this problem and make the jar file executable from any location of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Complete instructions may be found in `dist/README.TXT`:

> To distribute this project, zip up the dist folder (including the `lib` folder)
>   and distribute the ZIP file.

Comment: when i select `Clean And Build Main Project`, i see a zipped file that is the same name of my project. I checked `Compress Jar File` option in project properties, But i want to see Jar file of my project, Not zipped file!

Comment: Check the `Properties > Build > Packaging > Compress…` setting; ping me if you pose this question.

Comment: Finally i done it, But i see a `zip` file . And when i want to open it, the `winRAR` program opened and my program not executed!

Comment: @Sajad End user is expected to unzip the zip file manually and then run your jar.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the manifest inside of the jar file contains the necessary classpaths. If you are unfamiliar with the concept, go here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has probably included any external projects/libraries/Jars in the `dist/lib` folder.

In order to run the application, you must include all the files in the `dist` folder when you copy the application

Comment: I have tried this method and it works. so if i want to give my users the jar file alone as executable, how to overcome this problem of exporting whole folder ???

Comment: There's no one really "solution" per-say. If it's really, really important to you, you can try and merge all the separate Jar's together. This would require you to unjar all the jar files into a directory and the re-jar them as a single jar. This is dangerous as some of the Jars may contain resources with the same name. Another solution is to try something like [`One-Jar`](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) which basically Jar's the Jar's into a single Jar file and then uses a custom class loader to load you main application. Either solution has problems and takes extra work

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your projects Manifest.mf file has the Attribute 
"Main-Class" set to your projects current main Class file.